# Low copy performance in OpenCL (enqueueWriteBuffer & enqueueReadBuffer)

Tags: memory, copy, opencl

I was getting very low performance while copying memory between the GPU and the CPU (both ways) with enqueueWriteBuffer and enqueueReadBuffer. So I have written a test to be sure the problem was in those two functions and I still get a very low performance.

My tests are performing several copies, including 1GB copy and still the best result is around 3GB/s. In contrast, the CUDA test "bandwidthTest.exe" achieves around 12GB/s with a copy size of 30MB. I am running all the test in a laptop with a NVIDIA 1050 GTX and CUDA 10.0.

Any ideas why the performance might be so low?

This is the code I am using for testing, I am building it using Qt. So, there are some dependencies (QTime, QDebug):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "CL/cl.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

    std::vector<std::string> platformsNames;
    for (auto & platform : platforms) {
        platformsNames.push_back(platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>());
    }


    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    auto device = all_devices[0];
    qDebug() << "Platform used: " << platformsNames[0].c_str() << ". Device used: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>().c_str();
    qDebug() << "Max work group size: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE>();
    qDebug() << "Max items size: " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context);
    // 1KB, 1MB, 10MB, 100MB, 1GB
    size_t sizes[] = {1024, 1024 * 1024, 10 * 1024 * 1024, 100 * 1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024 * 1024};
    qDebug() << "Write Buffers";
    for (auto size : sizes) {
        cl::Buffer buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size);
        std::vector<unsigned char> t(size);
        QTime timerFFT;
        timerFFT.start();
        auto iterations = 100.0f;
        for (auto i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            int err = queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer, true, 0, size, t.data());
        }
        auto elapsed = timerFFT.elapsed() / 1000.0f;
        qDebug() << "GB/s: " << size / (1024.0f * 1024.0f * 1024.0f) / elapsed * iterations;
    }
    qDebug() << "Read Buffers";
    for (auto size : sizes) {
        cl::Buffer buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size);
        std::vector<unsigned char> t(size);
        QTime timerFFT;
        timerFFT.start();
        auto iterations = 100.0f;
        for (auto i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            int err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer, true, 0, size, t.data());
        }
        auto elapsed = timerFFT.elapsed() / 1000.0f;
        qDebug() << "GB/s: " << size / (1024.0f * 1024.0f * 1024.0f) / elapsed * iterations;
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: So that you're comparing apples to apples, what performance do you get with a copy size of 30MB?

Comment: @pmdj I am getting between 3.1GB/s and 3.4GB/s for a 30MB copy. The speed stays the same from 1MB to 1GB.

Comment: I'm surprised your numbers are not unexpectedly high since you need a clFinish before looking at the elaspsed of your timer. Otherwise you are only timing the enqueue, not the actual copy.

Comment: @Dithermaster as far as I know that is fine because I am making blocking calls to1 enqueueWriteBuffer and enqueueReadBuffer. Anyway, I have found out the problem, pinned memory! Everything was fine in the CUDA test because it was using pinned memory, while paginated memory was used in the OpenCL test.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. My code says `/*blocking_write*/CL_TRUE` so I'm used to seeing that instead of just `true`. Yes, pinned memory makes a big difference. Note: In NVIDIA's newer drivers, clEnqueueMapBuffer will automatically use pinned memory in many cases.